# Rails: Run a controller action from code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

I would like to automate a task in my Rails app, create a rake task, almost all the code I need is in a controller action, I would like to just call that controller action instead of write the "same" code in my task and save some lines of code. Is that possible?

Comment: No that is a bad design. Correct way is to create a PORO class, and then use that class to perform the logic both in controller and Rake tasks etc. This way you are adhering DRY.

Comment: If you have any links, or resources you know would be helpful, add them in an answer and I will mark your answer as accepted, thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for example. Say you have usecase to auto renew Stripe customers subscriptions from both Rake tasks and using client side . Now, you will write a PORO class like below:

```
class AutoRenewSubscription
  attr_reader :coupon, :email

  def initialize args = {}
    @email  = args[:email]
    @coupon = args[:coupon]
    #....
  end

  def run!
    user_current_plan.toggle!(:auto_renew)

    case action
    when :resume
      resume_subscription
    when :cancel
      cancel_subscription
    end
  end
  #... some more code as you need.
end
```

You can put the class inside `app/services/auto_renew_subscription.rb` folder. Now this class is available globally. So, call it inside the controller like :

```
class SubscriptionController < ApplicationController
  def create
   #.. some logic
   AutoRenewSubscription.new(
     coupon: "VXTYRE", email: 'some@email.com'
   ).run!
  end
end
```

And do call it from your rake task also :

```
desc "This task is to auto renew user subscriptions"
task :auto_renew => :environment do
  puts "auto renew."
  AutoRenewSubscription.new(
    coupon: "VXTYRE", email: 'some@email.com'
  ).run!
end
```

This is what I think good way to solve your issue. Hope you will like my idea. :)